# Trying to figure out localStorage and getItem command

Tags: javascript, wordpress, local-storage

I have some code that is connected to buttons that, when clicked, change the color theme of my site. The buttons work perfectly, but when I reload the page or go to a different one (that has the exact same code as this one), the color scheme goes away completely and everything that isn't an image is white, until I click one of the buttons. My goal is to 1) set the default color scheme to 'theme-dark-red' so the page automatically loads that theme, unless the previous page had a different theme, in which case 2) find a way for each page to load the theme of the last page. I'm pretty new to JS, but this my currently-malfunctioning code:

```
<script>
  // function to set a given theme/color-scheme
  function setTheme(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
  }

// functions to set specific themes
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark-purple') {
      setTheme('theme-dark-purple');
    }
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark-blue') {
      setTheme('theme-dark-blue');
    }
if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark-green') {
      setTheme('theme-dark-green');
    }
else setTheme('theme-dark-red');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see a function body around the if statements you've written. Are they (and how are they) getting triggered from somewhere?

Comment: The problem is caused by a typo in the code: `else setTheme('theme-dark-red');` is missing a `{` after `else`. You should be seeing an error on the developer console.

Comment: I'm not sure how to write a function body. And I have onclick functions attached to my buttons.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sure the localStorage is not read? If I see this code, then you are missing the if else statement on some places everywhere.

Because now or the `theme-dark-green` or `theme-dark-red` will be set

Or you can use the following shorter code:

```
function setTheme(themeName) {
    const themeList = ['theme-dark-purple', 'theme-dark-blue', 'theme-dark-green']
    const theme = themeList.indexOf(themeName)) < 0 ? 'theme-dark-red';
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}

setTheme(localStorage.getItem('theme'))
```

You can easily test in your code if the localstorage is read correct with the `console.log` command